# Subversion over ssh - access to the remote repository on Linux from Windows host

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn

I created a repository in **Mandriva Linux** and want to access it from Windows host.

```
mkdir /home/user/myrepo/
svnadmin create /home/user/myrepo/
```

To do this, i installed a client TortoiseSVN 1.7.9.

I set the path -

```
svn+ssh://user@ip/home/user/myrepo/
```

Where ip== ip of remote linux host.

I'm trying to do a review of the repository, but get an error -

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://user@ip/home/user/myrepo/' Can't create tunnel.
```

What could be the reason for the error?

Comment: Maybe a question for http://www.superuser.com/.

Comment: I saw nothing for server-side setup. Are you aware of this side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit your configuration file (%appdata%\Subversion\config), there is a section called `tunnels` where you have an out commented line like this:

```
ssh = C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoisePlink.exe
```

If you use a key for authorization you can add this parameter for skipping the password entry part:

```
-i c:\\Path\\to\\putty-ssh-key.ppk
```